# Parallel Data Warehouse - Scripting out Database

Tags: sql, parallel-processing, data-warehouse, pdw-file-browser

I have been tasked with scripting out the entire database with schema.  I have to use Visual Studio 2012  or SSMS 2014.  I don't really see a good wizard like normal to do this.  Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on your database -> Tasks -> Generate scripts and follow up the wizard

The wizard generates a script of all the objects in a database, or a subset of the objects that you select. The wizard has many options for your scripts, such as whether to include permissions, collation, constraints, and so on.